# How to create a exception for a while loop to repeat a input

Tags: python

I am trying to get this bit of code to work to validate the following input. I want to only accept inputs 1,2,or 3. Here is what I have so far:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number:'))
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        if number < 3:
            done = True
    except:
        number = input("Please enter a valid number:")
```

The expected out put that I want if the input to loop until I get either 1,2, or 3.
Right now it won't do anything to when I input something greater than three. I want to use this number as an input to another function. Any help would be great of if you need more information please let me know!

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is not converting the second call to `input` in the `except` block to an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
number = int(input('Enter a number:'))
done = False
while not done:
    if number <= 3:
        done = True
    else:
        number = int(input("Please enter a valid number:"))
```

`except` block only run when there is an error in `try` block code.

Use `if-else` statement.

You can use this one too.

```
number = int(input('Enter a number:'))
done = False
while number>3:
    number = int(input('Please enter a valid number:'))
```